# sequelize find and update a record without a model

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

I would like to update a database record using sequelize.js and mysql2
I do not have access to the models folder or either they have not been made so is there a way to update can't find solution all solutions are that i checked are with model name dot update

```
var Book = db.define(‘books’, {
 title: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 pages: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER
 }
})


Book.update(
   {title: req.body.title},
   {returning: true, where: {id: req.params.bookId} }
 )
 .then(function([ rowsUpdate, [updatedBook] ]) {
   res.json(updatedBook)
 })
 .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

I would like your expert solution on that please

Comment: @JitendraYadav accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For latest documentation based on version refer to [Sequelize ORM](https://sequelize.org/).

**Update - v6**

You can use both `query model(preferred)` as well as `raw queries` to achieve this.

```
// Using query model(User)
await User.update({ y: 42 }, {
  where: {
    x: 12
  }
});

// Using raw query
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET y = 42 WHERE x = 12");
// Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
```

**Old - v3**

```
sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET y = 42 WHERE x = 12").spread(function(results, metadata) {
  // Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
})
```

Reference: [Sequelize Raw Query](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/raw-queries/)